# PHP hanging on socket_read

Tags: java, php, sockets

I am trying to read a response from a socket I have written on a Java application. However the PHP is just hanging. Here is the code I am using to read from the socket:

```
while($resp = socket_read($socket, 1000)) {
   $str .= $resp;
   if (strpos($str, "\n") !== false) {
        break;
   }
}
```

When I run the socket call from terminal there is deffinately a response. This is what my response code is in Java:

```
out.println(request.seed);
```

Where request.seed is an int. I have also tried:

```
out.println(request.passcode + "\n");
```

But this didnt fix the problem.

---

When I request the following in terminal:

```
josephs-macbook:~ jf$ echo "pairBankRequest|userID=305,bankID=12," | nc 127.0.0.1 3030
```

I get the following reply:

```
830039
```

which is what is expected.

Answer (score 2):

In the PHP client program, insert `usleep(500)` between socket writes and read.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is hanging is because your buffer is larger than the data being sent.

If you lower your buffer from 1000 bytes to 1 byte, youll see that the script no longer hangs.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual:

> Optional type parameter is a named constant:
>
> PHP_BINARY_READ (Default) - use the system recv() function. Safe for reading binary data.
>     PHP_NORMAL_READ - reading stops at \n or \r.

**Source:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php

Have you tried using PHP_NORMAL_READ as the 3rd argument to socket_read()? This would also remove the need to check for `strpos($str, "\n")...`.

Just a shot in the dark, but I'd try that.

**Edit:**

Here's a snippet of code that works for me:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

...
// connecting the socket, etc
...

$result = '';
$numBytes = 100;
$numRead = 0;

while ($numRead < $numBytes)
{
  $tmp = socket_read($socket, $numBytes - $numRead, PHP_BINARY_READ);
  if ($tmp === false)
  {
    $error = socket_last_error();
    socket_close($socket);
    $socket = null;
    throw new Exception('Read error ('.$error.')');
  }
  $numRead += strlen($tmp);
  $result.= $tmp;
}
```

Comment: Hm. Do you know the number of bytes you're reading from the socket?

Comment: It was just a 6 digit number being returned. I have added an extra string to increase the length and set $numBytes as 1 but still the same problem.

Comment: I've added the socket creation code. Are you using the same args?

Comment: You said this works when you run it from a terminal. Could you describe the differences?

Comment: What's the return value you're getting from socket_write()?

Comment: If I print it I get 43, which is the length of the input string?

Comment: Does your java server show the exact same input when using both methods?

Comment: Yes - and it does the required operation if I dont have the socket_read part in the PHP code. If it is in there though then it hangs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6494/discussion-between-bhayden-and-lior-cohen)